# pine script code convert problem (upgrade version)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i want convert this code to pine script version 5

myPosition = buy==1 ? 0 : sell==1 or myPosition[1]==1 ? 1 : 0

This is version 2 code

I get this error when compiling : Undeclared identifier 'myPosition';

i think myPosition is array , but how to fix it , i define array but not work

thank you

Answer (score 1):

In new pine-script versions, you should define a variable first, in order to reference it during assignemtn.

Try something like this.

```
myPosition = 0
myPosition := buy==1 ? 0 : sell==1 or myPosition[1]==1 ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style=line
```

This is v3

Try in v5

```
style=plot.style_line
```